# admin-on-rest What testing tools/patterns are available?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there a resource somewhere that lays out all the best tools/patterns/approaches specifically for apps built using admin-on-rest?

I don't see anything in the documentation.

- https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/
- https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per README admin-on-rest includes listing, unit and functional tests by running:

`make test`

https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/#contributing